# How can I access $.velocity.RunSequence when using Velocity.js with Browserify?

Tags: browserify, velocity.js

My code:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
Backbone.$ = $;
var velocity = require('velocity-animate');

module.exports = function (obj) {

    var obj = obj || {};

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'article',
        className: 'lab-notes__article--single',
        initialize: function () {
            var _this = this;
            _this.collection.deferred.done(function () {
                var _thePost = _this.collection.first();
                _this.model = _this.collection.find(function(model) {
                    return model.get('slug') === data.slug;
                });
                _this.render();
            });
        },
        render: function () {
            var _this = this;
            var data = this.model.attributes;
            var JST = require('../templates/blog-post-single.html')(data);
            this.$el.html(JST);
            $('[data-blog-post-single]').html(this.el);

            var openBlogPost = [
                { e: $('body'), p: 'scroll', o: { duration: 100, duration: 500, easing: 'easeInOutQuart', } },
                { e: _this.$el, p: 'fadeIn', o: { duration: 200 } }
            ];
            $.velocity.RunSequence(openBlogPost);
        }
    });
};
```

… And the error I receive when running it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RunSequence' of undefined
```

That occurs on this line:

```
$.velocity.RunSequence(openBlogPost);
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but I have a feeling it has to do with how I'm requiring Velocity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work I had to change the require line from this:

```
var velocity = require('velocity-animate');
```

… to this:

```
velocity = $.velocity = require('velocity-animate');
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs contain a section about using browserify:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = require("path/to/jquery-x.x.x.js");
require("path/to/velocity.js");
// Optional: If you're using the UI pack, require it after Velocity. (You don't need to assign it to a variable.)
require("path/to/velocity.ui.js");
```

Instead of creating a local variable named `$` try creating it on the global (a.k.a `window`) scope, along with the `jQuery` namespace. Also, make sure `velocity-animate` points to the right file (as I recall it's the name of the package on npm, and not necessarily the path to Velocity in your project).

Comment: So changing `var $ = require('jquery');` to `window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Figured it out. Posting now.